# When to choose PopupRoute vs Overlay?

Tags: flutter

It appears like `PopupRoute` and `Overlay` are quite similar.

What are the main differences and advantages of each of them? And which one would you chose in which situations?

Answer (score 0):

I found one use-case for using overlay when you want to put some widget permanently above all the widgets like log-out button, cart or something.

Comment: `Overlay` seems to be the first choice, and it's for sure convenient, but I'm wondering if `PopupRoute` would be more performant or if it brings any other advantage.